# Problem about boundedness of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be an analytic function.Suppose $|f(1/n)|\leq1/n^{3/2} $ for each $n\in \mathbb N$.Prove that $\{n^2f(1/n)$} is bounded.

My attempt:I was trying that $|n^2f(1/n)|=|n^2||f(1/n)|\leq n^2.1/n^{3/2}=n^{1/2}$which is not giving anything.What is the correct approach?

Comment: Introduce $g(z)=f(z)/z$ and argue that $g(0)=0$; then factor $g$ accordingly.